# kotlin - ClassNotFoundException MainKt

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I have created a new project with `New Project -> Kotlin Multiplatform -> Library`. Then the IDE created few source trees in the root project, which I have removed and added a new module called `kmm`.

Now the problem I have is that there is no Run button next to main fun. If I run `run` task from `application` plugin, then I get

```
> Task :wrapper

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
> Task :kmm:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :kmm:processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :kmm:classes UP-TO-DATE

> Task :kmm:run FAILED
1 actionable task: 1 executed
Error: Could not find or load main class com.github.shalva97.MainKt
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.shalva97.MainKt

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':kmm:run'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.11.9-hotspot\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 256ms
11:02:41 PM: Execution finished 'run'.
```

So how can I run the code which is inside my new module?

Here is the root gradle:

```kotlin
group = "org.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Here is gradle for `kmm` module:

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.8.0-Beta"
    application
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1")
}

tasks.getByName<Test>("test") {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

kotlin {
    jvm()
    linuxArm64()

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting
    }
}

application {
    mainClass.set("com.github.shalva97.MainKt")
}
```

my Main.kt

```kotlin
package com.github.shalva97

fun main() {
    println(5.factorial())
}

fun Number.factorial(): Long {
    return (1..this.toLong()).fold(1) { i: Long, l: Long ->
        return l * i
    }
}
```

And here is the pic, maybe it will also help:
[image]

EDIT:

Here is the settings.gradle.kts:

```kotlin
rootProject.name = "Willians"

include("kmm")
```

Comment: Can you include the contents of `settings.gradle.kts`? Does it contain a line setting the name of the root project? (`rootProject.name=...`). Does it include the `kmm` subproject? (`include(":kmm")`)

Comment: yes, I have updated the question. Also added my project here https://github.com/shalva97/Willians/tree/fb2c3b51e7d0e599f356187ca82d3bd77cf79e51

Comment: I think a main function in commonMain is not supported https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-16919

Comment: Well, thats sad... I think I found a workaround for this, will add answer a bit later

Answer (score 0):

Here is my workaround I found.

add a new native target with `binaries` block

```kotlin
macosX64 {
    binaries {
        executable {
            entryPoint = "com.github.shalva97.main" // here main is the function name
        }
    }
}
```

and then in Gradle a new task should appear `runDebugExecutableMacosX64`, which will run and show the output.

There is actually 2 of them, not sure why but both work:

[image]

```
19:51:29: Executing 'runDebugExecutableMacosX64'...

> Task :wrapper

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
> Task :kmm:compileKotlinMacosX64
> Task :kmm:linkDebugExecutableMacosX64

> Task :kmm:runDebugExecutableMacosX64
[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 3s
3 actionable tasks: 3 executed
19:51:35: Execution finished 'runDebugExecutableMacosX64'.
```

Now `application` plugin seems useless, so I guess it can be removed.